# Headless server-Ignore X output without routing

Tags: x11, headless

I saw a lot of people that make headless server and route the X requests trough ssh using vnc or something like that.

Is there a way to completely ignore the x output and avoid error messages like:

Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly

Without executing the routing, just making a fake X server that just throw everything out?

Comment: Check [Xdummy](http://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Xdummy) and [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb).

Comment: Thanks i was already fiddling with xvfb will take a look at XDummy